# Inadvertently modifying a copy of my object

Tags: c++, pointers, deep-copy

I have a function where I pass in a pointer to an array of `MyClass` and I would like to create an object within the function and store it in the array. Currently I am inadvertently modifying a copy of my object, so that when the function returns the array of MyClass doesn't contain the changes I made. How should I change this? I presume an easy fix is to move the adding the object to the array at the end, but is there any way I can modify a reference to my newly-created object instead?

```
void x(MyClass* a){
    //Create object on stack
    MyClass my_obj(30);

    //Add object to array
    a[30] = my_obj;

    //These changes don't get made because the object in the array is a copy
    //of the object I created on the stack.
    my_obj.datamember[0] = 3;
    my_obj.datamember[1] = 7;

    //The array is "returned" because I am passing by pointer
}
```

Comment: In `void x( MyClass * a )`, is `a` a pointer to the beginning of an array of `MyClass *`? If so, how do `x()` know the length of the array? Can you show how `x()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `vector<MyClass>` instead.  Then you can simply do things like:

```
a.push_back(my_obj);
```

and

```
a.erase(a.remove(/*...*/));
```

Comment: So a vector contains references to the object?! I did not know this? I thought you had to declare std::vector<MyClass&> ? Is this the same for std::array?